# Separate angular 2 route config from main app file

Tags: split, routes, angular, config

I want to separate route config from app file into different file like (routeConfig.ts). It is possible?

For example:

```
import {Component} from 'angular2/core';
import {RouteConfig, ROUTER_DIRECTIVES} from 'angular2/router';
import {DashboardComponent} from './dashboard/dashboard.component';


import {MessagesComponent} from '../modules/messages/messages.component';


@Component({
    selector: 'app',
    directives: [
      ROUTER_DIRECTIVES
    ],
    templateUrl: './built/application/app.html'
})

@RouteConfig([
  {
    path: '/',
    name: 'Dashboard',
    component: DashboardComponent,
    useAsDefault: true
  }
])

export class AppComponent {}
```

I want to move  @RouteConfig params into different file and just load it inside main app file. It is possible? Thanks.   (Route config wil be wery big, so I want to split this).

First trouble, it is that when I try to move config into different file and just try to import JSON in app file  - I got errors with Undefined Component.   Because  componentsName it`s not a string. Can`t solve this issue.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can certainly move all the route definitions into a separate file.

In a file like route-definitions.ts:

```
import { RouteDefinition } from 'angular2/router';
import { HomeComponent } from './home/home.component';
import { AboutComponent } from './about/about.component';
import { InfoComponent } from './info/info.component';

export const RouteDefinitions: RouteDefinition[] = [
    {
        path: '/',
        name: 'Home',
        component: HomeComponent,
        useAsDefault: true
    },
    {
        path: '/about',
        name: 'About',
        component: AboutComponent
    },
    {
        path: '/info',
        name: 'Info',
        component: InfoComponent
    }
];
```

Then back in your app.component.ts file just do:

```
import { Component } from 'angular2/core';
import { RouteConfig, ROUTER_DIRECTIVES, ROUTER_PROVIDERS } from 'angular2/router';
import { RouteDefinitions } from './route-definitions';

@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    templateUrl: 'app/app.component.html',
    directives: [ROUTER_DIRECTIVES],
    providers: [
      ROUTER_PROVIDERS
    ]
})
@RouteConfig(RouteDefinitions)
export class AppComponent { }
```

Comment: Thanks Rob. I did it already (after couple of hours with pain and suffering).